# How to delete orphan images from Notes.app on Mac

Tags: macos, graphics, notes.app

I have an image that shows in the “Browse attachments” view in the Notes app on Mac, but when I right-click on it and choose *Show in Note*, it doesn’t return any note, as it was deleted previously.

Is there a way to remove this orphan image? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by going to *Show in Note* from iPhone — it showed an empty note and when I got back to the attachments view, the orphan one was gone. And it synced to the Mac as well.